# Delete grey border around canvas when exporting to PNG or JPEG

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

so basically I have an editor in which I am using FabricJS and React, the issue I am facing is regarding to the export, everytime I try to export in image format, the image has a rare botton and right grey border inside the image. [image: Here is a reference]

I use the following code for downloading and find no issues:

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #C00; 
}

.container{
  
}
.container button {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Fabric</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <canvas id="c" ></canvas>
    <br>
    <button id="downloadBtn">Convert Canvas into Image</button>
    <br>
    <span>Pls click here after clicking on Download Canvas button</span>
    <a href="#" > Download Image</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        // create a wrapper around native canvas element (with id="c")
        const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c", {
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    });

        // create a rectangle object
        const rect = new fabric.Rect({
            left: 100,
            top: 100,
            fill: 'red',
            width: 20,
            height: 20
        });

        // "add" rectangle onto canvas
        canvas.add(rect);   
        
        document.getElementById("downloadBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
        
      const data = canvas
                  .toDataURL();
              
      const a = document.createElement("a")
      a.href = data
      a.download = `drawing.png`
   
      a.click();
       document.getElementsByTagName("A")[0].setAttribute("href", data); 
        })
        
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone pls lend me hand since I can't find what can be causing this issue?

**Steps to reproduce with attached demo**:

1. Click first on "convertcanvas into image" button
2. click on the download image ( it is under an  tag)
3. right click on the red rect and select "save image as"
4. after having been saved into your files, open it and you'll see the borders on the right and bottom

Comment: your example isn't working

Comment: give it a look again pls

Comment: the example now runs but the download button throws an error

Comment: Try again pls, have just uploaded a new version, also pls note the steps to reproduce section ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use can just use css like that=>

Canvas{border:0;}

Comment: It is not shown on my canvas html element, but it shows when I export to PNG

Answer (score 0):

I believe the grey border you're seeing is a quirk of the photo viewer. My guess is you're using the Windows 10 Photos app for which others have noticed the same grey line ([see here](https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/why-did-unwanted-grey-border-line-display-in-photo-app-in-windows-10.136302/))

Try opening your saved image in a different program like Chrome and it should look correct.